# Simple SQL Query workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

My script for the pizza table is:

```
use sys;
 create table pizzas (
 name varchar(50),
 toppings varchar(50),
 price float);
  insert into pizzas (name, toppings, price) values ('margarita', 'cheese, tomato', 5.0);
insert into pizzas (name, toppings, price) values ('hawaiian', 'cheese, tomato, ham, pineapple', 5.5 );
insert into pizzas (name, toppings, price) values ('hot veggie', 'cheese,        tomato, chilli, onion', 5.5 );
```

I'm trying to create a query to determine which pizzas contain cheese..

What i've tried is:

SELECT pizzas
FROM
toppings
WHERE
toppings="$cheese$";

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name FROM pizzas WHERE toppings LIKE '%cheese%'
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the greatest database design, but if you use the LIKE syntax it should work for you

```
 SELECT pizzas FROM toppings WHERE toppings LIKE "%cheese%";
```

[Check the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html) for a full description of LIKE

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Query

SELECT * 
FROM PIZZAS
WHERE TOPPINGS like '%CHEESE%'